# Exact String parsing on antlr4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am having an issue while doing the parsing of my file.
Scenario as follows :

In the file i got to parse, i have values as follows

ABC/123/TEST

The first 3 letters are some kind of identifiers, and its the only way i can differ the various line

In grammar file:

```
file1: str1?;       

str1 : NEWLINE identifier1 SLANT INTEGER SLANT ALPHA;

INTEGER : [0-9]+;
ALPHA : [A-Z]+;
SLANT : '/';
NEWLINE : '/n';

identifier1 : 'ABC';
```

While running the parser, parser is not getting the line identifier as ABC, instead its giving me some strange error

```
mismatched input 'ABC' expecting 'ABC'
```

How can i parse against an exact string in antlr4?

Comment: Is there a space at the end ? Have you tried comparing them using == or .equals method. Can we see some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your lexer lexes `ABC` as an `ALPHA` instead of an `identifier1`. Here is why:

1. Your `identifier1` rules should rather be a lexer instead of a parser rule. So rename it to `IDENTIFIER1`
2. The `IDENTIFIER1` rule must be declared **before** the `ALPHA` rule, otherwise, `ALPHA` will always have higher precedence and `ABC` will be parsed as an `ALPHA` instead of an `IDENTIFIER1`. So be sure to move your `IDENTIFIER1` rule above the `ALPHA` rule, then everything should wok fine.

Comment: The reason for this is: the first lexer rule that produces the longest token wins. Using `'ABC'` in the parser rule `identifier1` implicitly creates a lexer rule for `ABC` at the same line, i.e. after the more generic `ALPHA`, which causes this rule to never be able to match.

Comment: Therefore: 1. Don't implicitly create lexer rules; 2. Sort the lexer rules from specific to general; 3. Never make a catchall lexer rule greedy (like `CATCH_ALL : .+;`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply guys.

I moved the IDENTIFIER1 to my lexer, before the ALPHA.

Works fine for me

cheers